# SSH access to GCP VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm using the CLI of the Cloud Sdk Docker image (google/cloud-sdk:latest), through a GitLab pipeline, in order to:

- Instantiate a VM (with no external IP)
- SSH connect to the VM

The VM is instantiating and running OK, and I can ssh it through the Cloud Shell terminal.
Now, when I want to SSH it with the CLI on the GitLab pipeline, I get the error: *root@compute.(..): Permission denied (publickey).*.

So I ran the command with **--troubleshoot** option:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone $CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE $VM_NAME  --project $CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT  --troubleshoot
```

and I got:

> External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
> Starting ssh troubleshooting for instance
> https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/(...)
> in zone europe-west1-b' Start time: 2021-11-23 11:15:17.120669
> ---- Checking network connectivity ---- The troubleshooting tool needs permission to check the VM's network  connectivity. Is it OK to run
> this test? (Y/n)?   Enabling service
> [networkmanagement.googleapis.com] on project [(...)]... Your
> source IP address is (...) Network Connectivity Test Result:
> REACHABLE EndpointInfo <EndpointInfo  destinationIp: '(...)'
> destinationNetworkUri:
> 'projects/(...)/global/networks/default'  destinationPort: 22
> protocol: 'TCP'  sourceIp: '(...)'  sourcePort: 56948> Initial
> state: packet originating from Internet. START_FROM_INTERNET
> Forwarding state: arriving at a Compute Engine instance.
> ARRIVE_AT_INSTANCE Config checking state: verify INGRESS firewall rule. APPLY_INGRESS_FIREWALL_RULE
> Final state: packet delivered to instance. DELIVER
> ---- Checking user permissions ---- User permissions: 0 issue(s) found.
> ---- Checking VPC settings ---- VPC settings: 0 issue(s) found.
> ---- Checking VM status ---- VM status: 0 issue(s) found.
> ---- Checking VM boot status ---- VM boot: 0 issue(s) found.

The thing is that no issue is found from the network connectivity tests. What can I check additionally to find out what's wrong?

Thanks for the help,

Guilhem.

Comment: Compute vms with internal ip can be able to ssh using Cloud IAP. And the user who is trying to connect this way, should either be a gcp project `Owner` or `IAP-Secured Tunnel User`. Please refer to this document for more information - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RajKumarN.
The service account I'm using to try to connect in SSH does have the role `IAP-secured Tunnel User`, yet the connection fails with `root@compute.(...): Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: @RajKumarN Finally found out, I added `gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE` and I could perform the SSH connection to the VM.

Answer (score 2):

The missing piece in my GCP configuration was the configuration of OS Login.
So I added the following instruction:

`gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE`

and was able then to connect to SSH to the Google VM.

As a recap, to connect to my GCP VM with no external address, I needed to:

- Enable `IAP-Secured Tunnel User` for the service account in IAM
- Define a firewall ingress rule to allow SSH (allow-ssh-ingress-from-iap)
- Activate oslogin, with `gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE`
- Set compute zone and compute region